# How to get SPWebApplication for current request in HttpModule?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, httpmodule

How can I get the SPWebApplication for the current request from a HttpModule?

Answer (score 1):

try constructing the SPSite yourself

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(app.Context.Request.Url.ToString())) { //might need to trim the url
    site.WebApplication
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried `SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication` ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to get this in the Init method of a custom HttpModule where the SPContext is null.